# How to change rotation radius on the go with OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I have a map I want to rotate around a point with a certain radius. 
I managed to do that, but my problem is I want to sometimes change the radius on the go and update the camera accordingly

```
pygame.init()
display = (1700, 1000)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(50, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 5000)

glTranslatef(1, 1, -(radius/2))
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glRotatef(10, 1, 0, 0) # i gave it 10 degrees for the camera to look at 
                       # the ground 
gluLookAt(offset_x - radius / 2, height, offset_z - radius / 2,
          offset_x, 0, offset_z,
          0, 1, 0)

# offset_x,offset_z are the center of the circle, 
# and the distance of rotation is the radius.
# This gets me to the point i want to be, everything is good so far. 

while True: 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glPushMatrix()

    if not move: 
        glTranslatef(offset_x, 0, offset_z)
        glRotatef(rotation_angle, 0, 1, 0)
        glTranslatef(-offset_x, 0, -offset_z)
        rotation_angle += 0.5
    else:
        glTranslatef(offset_x, 0, offset_z)
        glRotatef(rotation_angle, 0, 1, 0)
        glTranslatef(-offset_x, 0, -offset_z)
    #### this rotates around the point at the start.
    #### the radius and the view distance is perfect.
```

Now I get a new radius from a text file, and I want to change the view to rotate around the new radius center from the new radius distance. 
I have this "if" that knows when radius changed, but I don't understand how to use the glTranslatef() or gluLookAt() to change the rotation around the new point.

```
    #####################################################
    if radius_changed:
        glTranslatef(0, 0, radius - old_radius_copy) # this isnt working

        radius_changed = False
    else:
         glTranslatef(0, 0, radius - old_radius_copy) # this isnt working
    ######################################################


    glCallList(obj.gl_list)
    DrawBuffer(bufferObj, noPoints, noCirclePoints, noCrossPoints)
    glPopMatrix()
```

Answer (score 1):

using glScalef() would get the right result, as the following:

```
    if radius_changed:
        delta =  float(old_radius_copy) / float(radius)
        print delta
        scale_param_for_radius_change *= delta
        glTranslatef(offset_x, 0, offset_z)
        glScalef(scale_param_for_radius_change, 1, scale_param_for_radius_change)
        glTranslatef(-offset_x, 0, -offset_z)
        old_radius_copy = radius
        radius_changed = False
    else:
        glTranslatef(offset_x, 0, offset_z)
        glScalef(scale_param_for_radius_change, 1, scale_param_for_radius_change)
        glTranslatef(-offset_x, 0, -offset_z)
```